# Write and send JSON file from asp

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

Just a disclaimer: I am by no means a c#/.net programmer.

I would like to send a json object in the query string to a .aspx page (AJAX) and then have that file download automatically in the client (jQuery or JS).

Here is my current file `upload.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8"%>

<script runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string json = "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"name\": \"Test 1\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"name\": \"Test 2\"}]";
        Response.Clear(); 
        Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
        Response.Write(json); 
        Response.End();              
    }  
</script>
```

How can I get this to work?

Also, as a side thing, would it be possible to send this as a custom file extension (after modifying the MIME types on the server config).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define `download automatically`

Comment: Browser recognizes it as an "application" type file, and begins the download without the user interacting.

Comment: I have done a "chrome" only solution (not sure what other browsers are supported) using the download attribute on an anchor, and setting the href to "data:application/json...etc". This is nice because it instantly saves the file. That is the functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

**Jquery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Login.aspx/checkUserNameAvail",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'iuser':'" + userid + "'}",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (msg) {
        $(msg).find("Table").each(function () {
            var username = $(this).find('UserName').text();
            if (username != '') {
                //window.location.replace('/iCalendar.aspx');
                alert('This username already taken..');
                $("#reguser").val('');
                $("#reguser").focus();
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (d) {
    }
});
```

**.cs**

```
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static string checkUserNameAvail(string iuser)
    {
        try
        {
            iCalendarClass iC = new iCalendarClass();
            DataSet ds = iC.checkUserNameAvail(iuser);
            return (ds.GetXml());
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```